# Firewall locks me out of ssh

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, iptables, centos5

Just trying to make a simple script that will configure iptables to block all incoming and outgoing traffic except for ssh on default port 22 and udp on port 8888.

This is what i have:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Flush all current rules from iptables
#
iptables -F

#
# Set default policies for INPUT, FORWARD and OUTPUT chains
#
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

#
# Allow SSH connections on tcp port 22
#
iptables -A INPUT -i eto0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eto0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#
# Set access for localhost
#
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

#
# Accept connections on 8888 for vpn access from client
#
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 8888 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --sport 8888 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#
# Apply forwarding for OpenVPN Tunneling
#
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT     
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0./24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE   
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT

#
# Enable forwarding
# 
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

#
# List rules
#
iptables -L -v
```

But when i run it i get locked out of my vps and have to restart it in order to get back in. I really can't see where i am going wrong... also the vpn won't work after running this firewall.

I also wanted to block all pings to the public ip on all ports but have no idea how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for you being locked out on the reason is "eto0!=eth0" , and configure the policies in the end after you have configured all of your rules and you have allowed all outgoing traffic on all interfaces.

for ping related rules do `man iptables` and read on **icmp**

Also, in future create a allow all rule something like

`/sbin/iptables -P INPUT ALLOW` and the same for OUTPUT and FORWARD and put it on your cron to run every 5/10 minutes that way you would get to login even if something goes out of hands.